# Enable Postman client side cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, postman

I am having issues testing cache for some of our API's through Postman App.

I have disabled "Send nocache header", but all request are still hitting the server. I have testet both against localhost:4561(IISExpress) and our test environment. I have also tested with a custom HttpClient, which worked fine. Why will Postman not serve from cache?

**Request headers:**

```
postman-token:"82eb1770-48e0-4024-bc7e-369c15004f74"
x-applicationid:"Postman - 69811"
user-agent:"PostmanRuntime/6.4.1"
accept:"*/*"
host:"localhost:48868"
accept-encoding:"gzip, deflate"
```

**Response**

```
cache-control:"max-age=28800"
content-type:"application/xml; charset=utf-8"
content-encoding:"gzip"
vary:"Accept"
access-control-allow-origin:"*"
access-control-allow-headers:"Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-ApplicationId, X-SessionId, X-RequestId"
access-control-allow-methods:"GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS"
date:"Thu, 25 Oct 2018 06:36:01 GMT"
content-length:"108"
```

**Using:**
Postman for Windows
Version 5.3.2
win32 10.0.15063 / x64

Comment: Hi Anders, any update on how to enable cache with Postman? to prevent it hitting server with cache-control?

Answer (score 0):

Under preferences > Uncheck Send no-cache header

[image]